# Billling address and shipping_address populate from billing_address_id and shipping_address_id in magento 2

Tags: shipping-address, order-grid

I need to known how Billing address and Shipping address is populate in **sales_order_grid**  table from **sales_order** table Even in the sales_order table there is billing_address_id and shipping_address_id is placed .

How billing_address and shipping_address populate in sales_order_grid from billing_address_id and shipping_address_id ?

Comment: You want to show in admin sales order grid?

Comment: yes i show it . it work but issue in filtering .

Answer (score 0):

I have created custom module to get billing address and shipping address column to Sales Order Grid.

Check the below files and code.

> app/code/Mymodule/CustomOrderGrid/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="billing_address" class="Mymodule\CustomOrderGrid\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\BillingAddress">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Billing Address</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="shipping_address" class="Mymodule\CustomOrderGrid\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ShippingAddress">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping Address</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

> app/code/Mymodule/CustomOrderGrid/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/BillingAddress.php

```
<?php
    namespace Mymodule\CustomOrderGrid\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

    use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
    use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
    use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
    use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
    use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

    class BillingAddress extends Column
    {
        protected $_orderRepository;
        protected $_searchCriteria;

        public function __construct(ContextInterface $context, UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory, OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository, SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria, array $components = [], array $data = [])
        {
            $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
            $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
            parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        }

        public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
        {
            if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
                foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

                    $billingAddress = $item["billing_address"];
                    $item[$this->getData('name')] = $billingAddress;
                }
            }

            return $dataSource;
        }
    }
```

> app/code/Mymodule/CustomOrderGrid/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/ShippingAddress.php

```
<?php
    namespace Mymodule\CustomOrderGrid\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

    use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
    use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
    use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
    use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
    use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

    class ShippingAddress extends Column
    {
        protected $_orderRepository;
        protected $_searchCriteria;

        public function __construct(ContextInterface $context, UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory, OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository, SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria, array $components = [], array $data = [])
        {
            $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
            $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
            parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        }

        public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
        {
            if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
                foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

                    $shippingAddress = $item["shipping_address"];
                    $item[$this->getData('name')] = $shippingAddress;
                }
            }

            return $dataSource;
        }
    }
```

Hope it will work for you.

Also, Filter options working in my case, Please check this screenshot

[image]

Comment: kishor ? why you create billing_address and shipping_address columns? by default magento has developed both columns . 

your filtering is working because your column names are billing_address and shipipng_address that are already exist in database .